# Surface 4 went to zero battery, and now will not stay running

Tags: microsoft-surface

This is a brand new Surface 4, unboxed 4 days ago.

Issue #1: Surface 4 keeps shutting down with no warning.

It is plugged in, 0% battery charge. Boots up runs fine for a few minutes, then shuts down with no warning.

Issue #2  used the surface. Closed cover and threw in my bag for two days. Take it out, and the battery is at zero. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Return it. Depending on where you’re from or where you bought it, a warranty might be required by law or part of a voluntary program by the seller.

Comment: Is the unit brand new? I'm pretty sure your unit has a faulty battery.

Comment: @DanielB OP updated

Comment: @bwDraco OP updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely it or it's battery are just near-DOA. Either see about returning it to where you bought it or submit it for warranty replacement.

Comment: I returned it. Very nice device, but between the funny kbd layout and the hardware funniness, back it went.